# Is there an 'upgrade_to_unique_lock' for boost::interprocess?

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess, multiprocess

I am looking for the best way to effectively share chunks of data between two (or more) processes in a **writer-biased** reader/writer model.

My current tests are with `boost::interprocess`. I have created some `managed_shared_memory` and am attempting to lock access to the data chunk by using an interprocess mutex stored in the shared memory.

However, even when using `sharable_lock` on the reader and `upgradable_lock` on the writer, **the client will read fragmented values during write operations instead of blocking**. While doing a similar reader/writer setup between threads in a single process, I used `upgrade_to_unique_lock` to solve this issue. However, I have not found its `boost::interprocess` equivalent. Does one exist?

Server (writer):

```
while (1) {
  // Get upgrade lock on the mutex
  upgradable_lock <MutexType> lock(myMutex);

  // Need 'upgrade_to_unique_lock' here so shared readers will block until
  // write operation is finished.

  // Write values here
}
```

Client (reader)

```
while (1)
{
  // Get shared access
  sharable_lock <MutexType> lock(myMutex);

  // Read p1's data here -- occasionally invalid!
}
```

I guess the bigger question at hand is this: is an interprocess mutex even the proper way to access shared memory between processes in a writer-biased setup?

*Note: using Boost 1.44.0*

Comment: I have moved your solution to a community wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Boost.Interprocess upgradable locks support upgrade per [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.upgradable_mutexes.upgradable_whats_a_mutex).  Definition [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/interprocess_upgradable_id829946.html).

Regarding your broader question - I would think that this is precisely what you want.  Readers can still work concurrently, and you have to prevent concurrent writes.  Unless you can partition the shared memory such that more constrained access is guaranteed, this looks the best.

Comment: Thanks. That got me digging in the right direction. I had looked at the docs several times but sometimes I'm a little thick-skulled. Specifically what I was missing was the `unlock_upgradable_and_lock` call which seems to do exactly what I needed -- block readers until writer is finished writing.

Comment: Is the answer two years later that this facility from `boost::thread` still not in `boost::interprocess`?  `upgrade_to_unique_lock` I mean.  It seems a logical thing to have.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

The answer, as stated in the question comments is to use the member function `unlock_upgradable_and_lock`. If there is an `boost::interprocess` analog to `upgrade_to_unique_lock`, I don't know where it is. But the `writer()` function can be rewritten as:

```
while (1) {
  // Get upgrade lock on the mutex
  myMutex.lock_upgradable();

  // Get exclusive access and block everyone else
  myMutex.unlock_upgradable_and_lock();

  // Write values here

  // Unlock the mutex (and stop blocking readers)
  myMutex.unlock();
}
```