# Interprocess reader/writer lock with Boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989795/example-for-boost-shared-mutex-multiple-reads-one-write) is gold when it comes to explaining how to implement reader/writer locks with Boost. It seems relatively simple and I really love it but it also seems to be using a non-named lock and I need an interprocess solution (doesn't need to be portable, can be Windows-only).

Is there a way to have an interprocess `shared_mutex`? I see there is a [`named_mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_mutex.html) but I can't get it to work with [`shared_lock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.shared_lock) ot other locks.

Any pointers are appreciated.

[EDIT]

In the meantime, I have come across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157491/is-there-an-upgrade-to-unique-lock-for-boostinterprocess-resolved) which almost hits the nail on the head. I have two issues:

1. it doesn't show complete code (I am guessing I need to use `named_upgradable_mutex` but I am not quite sure) and
2. I don't like the answer for the modified "writer" which uses no off the shelf class that does unlocking in destructor but a sequence of 3 raw calls on the mutex.

Comments or good solutions are still welcome.

Comment: Note that even using the scoped_lock or shared_lock won't protect you against leaving the interprocess mutex locked, in event of a program crash.  I found I needed to write a utility to call boost::interprocess::named_upgradable_mutex::remove(), to clean up the mutex after such an incident.  On linux, this seems to call shm_unlink(), though I'm not certain that's all it does.  BTW, you can see your named locks in /dev/shm/.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Boost.Interprocess documentation describes the so-called [upgradable mutexes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.upgradable_mutexes) it supports and the [upgradable mutex operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.upgradable_mutexes.upgradable_mutexes_operations) for the two supported upgradable mutex types:

- [`boost::interprocess::interprocess_upgradable_mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/interprocess_upg_id1004155.html), a non-recursive, anonymous upgradable mutex that can be placed in shared memory or memory mapped files.
- [`boost::interprocess::named_upgradable_mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_upgradable_mutex.html), a non-recursive, named upgradable mutex.

**EDIT:** I believe this works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_upgradable_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/sharable_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/upgradable_lock.hpp>

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439099/interprocess-reader-writer-lock-with-boost/

#define SHARED_MEMORY_NAME "SO12439099-MySharedMemory"

struct shared_data {
private:
    typedef boost::interprocess::interprocess_upgradable_mutex upgradable_mutex_type;

    mutable upgradable_mutex_type mutex;
    volatile int counter;

public:
    shared_data()
        : counter(0)
    {
    }

    int count() const {
        boost::interprocess::sharable_lock<upgradable_mutex_type> lock(mutex);
        return counter;
    }

    void set_counter(int counter) {
        boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<upgradable_mutex_type> lock(mutex);
        this->counter = counter;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::interprocess;

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " WHICH" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    const std::string which = argv[1];
    if (which == "parent") {
        shared_memory_object::remove(SHARED_MEMORY_NAME);
        shared_memory_object shm(create_only, SHARED_MEMORY_NAME, read_write);

        BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(argc) {
            shared_memory_object::remove(SHARED_MEMORY_NAME);
        } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END;

        shm.truncate(sizeof (shared_data));

        // Map the whole shared memory into this process.
        mapped_region region(shm, read_write);

        // Construct the shared_data.
        new (region.get_address()) shared_data;

        // Go to sleep for a minute.
        sleep(60);

        return 0;
    } else if (which == "reader_child") {
        shared_memory_object shm(open_only, SHARED_MEMORY_NAME, read_write);

        mapped_region region(shm, read_write);
        shared_data& d = *static_cast<shared_data *>(region.get_address());

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
            std::cout << "reader_child: " << d.count() << std::endl;
        }
    } else if (which == "writer_child") {
        shared_memory_object shm(open_only, SHARED_MEMORY_NAME, read_write);

        mapped_region region(shm, read_write);
        shared_data& d = *static_cast<shared_data *>(region.get_address());

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
            d.set_counter(i);
            std::cout << "writer_child: " << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this on a Mac with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
./a.out reader_child &
./a.out reader_child &
./a.out writer_child &
./a.out reader_child &
./a.out reader_child &
```

(You have to start the parent first: `./a.out parent`)

The output showed interleaving of "reader_child" and "writer_child" lines (with all of the "reader_child" lines showing a non-zero value after the first "writer_child" line), so it appears to be working.

Comment: Thanks! Does the trick for me even though it is not exactly what I was looking for it cleared some doubts.

Comment: why do you use volatile when counter is guarded by a lock?

Comment: @BryanFok: I used `volatile` because I didn't see any memory barrier guarantees when locking an `interprocess_upgradable_mutex`. There are three implementations: posix, windows, and spin. If using the posix or windows implementations, I don't think `volatile` is needed because pthread_mutex_lock() / WaitForSingleObject() is called behind the scenes. The spin implementation uses an atomic CAS operation, and I think that there are architectures where CAS does not have memory barrier guarantees. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24143387/196844), for example.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545417/how-can-i-attain-distributed-shared-memory