# Ordering of read/write operations in a C++ queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, caching, mutex

Let's assume we have a `SyncQueue` class with the following implementation:

```
class SyncQueue {
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<ComplexType> > m_q;
public:
    void push(const std::shared_ptr<ComplexType> & ptr) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        m_q.push(ptr);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<ComplexType> pop() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        std::shared_ptr<ComplexType> rv(m_q.front());
        m_q.pop();
        return rv;
    }
};
```

then we have this code that uses it:

```
SyncQueue q;

// Thread 1, Producer:
std::shared_ptr<ComplexType> ct(new ComplexType);
ct->foo = 3;
q.push(ct);

// Thread 2, Consumer:
std::shared_ptr<ComplexType> ct(q.pop());
std::cout << ct->foo << std::endl;
```

Am I guaranteed to get `3` when `ct->foo` is printed? `mtx` provides happens-before semantics for the pointer itself, but I'm not sure that says anything for the memory of `ComplexType`. If it is guaranteed, does it mean that every mutex lock (`std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);`) forces full cache-invalidation for any modified memory locations up-till the place where memory hierarchies of independent cores merge?

Comment: Uh, what if thread 2 acquires the mutex before thread 1?

Comment: Any data that is written to memory causes that cache-line to be invalidated, but I don't know what would make you say "forces full cache-invalidation"

Comment: @Brian - Yes, correct - assume that the sequence is as shown above.

Comment: This answer to an older questions suggests that yes, mutex functions issue memory barrier instructions if required by the hardware: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24143387/1401351

Comment: @Peter - that's great. As a clarification, does that mean that any writes, by any thread or process on that core's L1 and L2 will be marked as invalid across all other cores' caches, right?

Comment: `ct->foo = 3` happens-before `std::cout << ct->foo`, and so therefore the latter is guaranteed to observe the side effect of the former. The assignment is sequenced-before  `q.push(ct)`, which happens-before `q.pop()`, which is sequenced-before read access to `ct->foo`. "happens-before" relationship is transitively closed over "happens-before" and "sequenced-before" edges. Cashes and cores are irrelevant implementation details.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I certainly agree and I agree that "cashes and cores are irrelevant implementation details" in regards to semantics but I make it related to my question because it affects performance in multicore implementations i.e. every recent CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::mutex() is conformant to Mutex requirements (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Mutex)

> Prior m.unlock() operations on the same mutex synchronize-with this
>   lock operation (equivalent to release-acquire std::memory_order)

release-acquire is explained here (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

> **Release-Acquire ordering**
>
> If an atomic store in thread A is tagged
>   memory_order_release and an atomic load in thread B from the same
>   variable is tagged memory_order_acquire, **all memory writes (non-atomic
>   and relaxed atomic) that happened-before the atomic store from the
>   point of view of thread A, become visible side-effects in thread B**,
>   that is, once the atomic load is completed, thread B is guaranteed to
>   see everything thread A wrote to memory.
>
> The synchronization is
>   established only between the threads releasing and acquiring the same
>   atomic variable. Other threads can see different order of memory
>   accesses than either or both of the synchronized threads.

Code example in this section is very similar on yours. So it should be guaranteed that all writes in thread 1 will happen before mutex unlock in push().

Of course if "ct->foo = 3" hasn't any special tricky meaning where actual assignment happens in another thread :)

wrt cache-invalidation, from cppreference:

> On strongly-ordered systems (x86, SPARC TSO, IBM mainframe),
>   release-acquire ordering is automatic for the majority of operations.
>   No additional CPU instructions are issued for this synchronization
>   mode, only certain compiler optimizations are affected (e.g. the
>   compiler is prohibited from moving non-atomic stores past the atomic
>   store-release or perform non-atomic loads earlier than the atomic
>   load-acquire). On weakly-ordered systems (ARM, Itanium, PowerPC),
>   special CPU load or memory fence instructions have to be used.

So it really depends from the architecture.

Comment: "Of course if "ct->foo = 3" hasn't any special tricky meaning" Sure! :)