# Do the glibc implementation of pthread_spin_lock() and pthread_spin_unlock() function have memory fence instructions?

Tags: pthreads, glibc, spinlock

Do the glibc implementation of pthread_spin_lock() and pthread_spin_unlock() function have memory fence instructions?  (I could not find any fence instructions.)

Similar question has answers here.
[Does pthread_mutex_lock contains memory fence instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137964/does-pthread-mutex-lock-contains-memory-fence-instruction/24138417#24138417)

Answer (score 2):

> Do the glibc implementation of pthread_spin_lock() and pthread_spin_unlock() function have memory fence instructions?

There is no *the* implementation -- there is *an* implementation for each supported processor.

The `x86_64` implementation does not use memory fences; it uses `lock` prefix instead:

```
gdb -q /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0

(gdb) disas pthread_spin_lock
Dump of assembler code for function pthread_spin_lock:
   0x00000000000108c0 <+0>:     lock decl (%rdi)
   0x00000000000108c3 <+3>:     jne    0x108d0 <pthread_spin_lock+16>
   0x00000000000108c5 <+5>:     xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00000000000108c7 <+7>:     retq   
   0x00000000000108c8 <+8>:     nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x00000000000108d0 <+16>:    pause  
   0x00000000000108d2 <+18>:    cmpl   $0x0,(%rdi)
   0x00000000000108d5 <+21>:    jg     0x108c0 <pthread_spin_lock>
   0x00000000000108d7 <+23>:    jmp    0x108d0 <pthread_spin_lock+16>
```

Since `lock`-prefixed instructions are already a memory barrier on `x86_64` (and `i386`), no additional memory barriers are necessary.

But powerpc implementation uses `lwarx` and `stwcx` [instructions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/assembler/idalangref_lwarx_lwri_instrs.html), which are closer to "memory fence", and sparc64 implementation uses full `membar` (memory barrier) instruction.

You can see the various implementations in `sysdeps/.../pthread_spin_lock.*` files in GLIBC sources.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the x86_64 implementation does not need memory fences, because x86 locked instructions are a barrier.